# Sort of std class object PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi gotta array of Std class objects like

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => sven
)

[1] => stdClass Object(

    [id] => 88
    [name] => pat
)

[2] => stdClass Object(
    [id] => 63
    [name] => dan
)

)
```

and a order array like

```
$order = array(88,2,63);
```

how to sort it by my custom order? i tried to usort like

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a, $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b, $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

with no success because of the std class array_search will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filp the order array, then compare the $order array of their value in 0, 1, 2.

```
$order = array_flip($order);
usort($myArray, function($a, $b)use($order){return $order[$a->id] > $order[$b->id];});
```